# in cycle pass in values for terminal-like command inside jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, argparse

Could not find a way to pass in values for terminal-like command inside jupyter notebook when I run some script with argparse:

```
!python train.py --img 512 --batch 8 --epochs 40
```

Need iterativly run that script with different values of number of epochs: 10,40,70,100. Like:

```
!python train.py --img 512 --batch 8 --epochs 10
!python train.py --img 512 --batch 8 --epochs 40
!python train.py --img 512 --batch 8 --epochs 70
!python train.py --img 512 --batch 8 --epochs 100
```

Comment: Please remember to accept and upvote the answer if it solved your question ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a python variable to a command line environment (`!`) prefixing it with `$`:
And you can run a command line execution inside python code as well:

```py
epochs = [10, 40, 70, 100]
for e in epochs:
    !echo $e
```

Output:

```
10
40
70
100
```

Your jupyter cell should look like this:

```py
epochs = [10, 40, 70, 100]
for e in epochs:
    !python train.py --img 512 --batch 8 --epochs $e
```